# Summing totals from same date ranges, and getting the range value for those totals

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have the following data currently in PowerBI

[image]

This is totals for multiple entities that are under the same location (ID 1).

What I would like to produce is the following

[image]

Which is the summation of the 3 totals over time, with start and end dates of when they applied.

I will eventually try to use this to show a trending chart over time for how the totals changed.

Is something like this even possible in PowerBI and/or DAX to first produce the results and then report a trend line like that? The trend line in this example would just have the 3 data points.

The only thing I can think of right now is to extrapolate out each range to 1 day at a time per original screenshots rows, and make the granularity of the chart daily, instead of ranges like this. Then the summation becomes a lot simpler as its just be ID and Date. Only concern is the data volumes that will be produced by extrapolating this out by days like that.

Comment: On the trend chart, what do you want to see on X-axis?
By the way, your example seems incorrect - it accumulates backwards

Comment: The X axis would be time (the 3 ranges) the Y would be Total

The column name is probably confusing, its just a sum of the values that fall into the range, so the first row falls out of range on the second row and so on